# convert a not transparent GIF to transparent GIF in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, gif

Is it possible to convert a GIF image with a solid background to GIF with transparent background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You merely have to remove the background from the layers/frames.

Or set a transparent color in the Save For Web dialog....

In the `Save For Web` dialog.. click the color (or range of colors by holding Shift) in the **Color Table** which you want to be transparent... then click the little `Transparency` box below the Color Table... that color is made transparent.

[image]